# Issue with rounding data and NaN when using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, rounding, import-from-csv

I am trying to load a csv into a data frame using pandas.read_csv. My data has a column of cell ids that are 18 digits long, and then other columns with other data. Sometimes there is an empty entry, as shown below:

| root_id_orig | root_id_final | coarse_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 648518346489344345 | 648518346489344345 | local |
| 648518346509145466 |  |  |
| 648518346489461189 | 648518346489461189 | intersegmental |

When I use pandas.read_csv, it reads in the empty spaces as NaNs, which is good, but then it also rounds the 18 digit numbers. I can force it to display all 18 digits, but then it will replace the last two digits seemingly randomly, so that '648518346489344345' becomes '648518346489344308.'

I would like to load in the data and avoid this rounding issue, but still have something like NaN in the empty entries, so that I know to ignore them later. Alternatively, I could just drop the rows with the empty entries, since honestly I do that later anyway. Any advice?

Edit: actual pandas output --

test1 = csv of data with no spaces/missing entries
test2 = csv of data with missing entries

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%18.0f' % x)
segIDs1 = pd.read_csv(csv_path+'test1.csv')
segIDs2 = pd.read_csv(csv_path+'test2.csv')
print(segIDs1)
print(segIDs2)
```

segIDs1 prints as the following:

```
 root_id_orig       root_id_final       coarse_id
0    648518346492622267  648518346492622267           local
1    648518346490149896  648518346490149896  intersegmental
2    648518346475243320  648518346475243320           local
3    648518346486220960  648518346486220960           local
4    648518346486220960  648518346491547966  intersegmental
..                  ...                 ...             ...
348  648518346494699683  648518346526246871              MN
349  648518346491602705  648518346499802323           local
350  648518346492012120  648518346503946592           local
351  648518346476192927  648518346499062337           local
352  648518346493059320  648518346492999344  intersegmental

[353 rows x 3 columns]
```

segIDs2 prints as the following:

```
 root_id_orig      root_id_final       coarse_id
0    648518346492622267 648518346492622208           local
1    648518346490149896 648518346490149888  intersegmental
2    648518346475243320 648518346475243264           local
3    648518346486220960 648518346486220928           local
4    648518346486220960 648518346491547904  intersegmental
..                  ...                ...             ...
529  648518346475585266                NaN             NaN
530  648518346472501734                NaN             NaN
531  648518346471918758                NaN             NaN
532  648518346468216120                NaN             NaN
533  648518346468216120                NaN             NaN

[534 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I typically read the column as a string. Sometimes I need to slice it a bit. You can use pd.DataFrame.pad to add back 0's if needed.

Comment: I think you are misdiagnosing the issue.  My guess is that you are VIEWING the CSV file in Excel.  Although Python and pandas will handle 18-digit integers just fine, Excel does not.  It is forced to convert them to floating point, and floating point numbers only have about 17 digits of precision.  Show us your CSV file and the actual pandas output.

Comment: I am definitely not misdiagnosing the issue. I am aware of the issue in excel, this is separate. I edited my entry to include the actual pandas output and you can see the difference in the two cases. I think this has to do with how having NaNs forces pandas to use float for the numbers? Dropping the rows with the empty entries is my best bet, but I can only find information on how to drop those rows AFTER reading in the csv, by which point I will have already had the rounding error happen.

I am unsure how to show the actual csv file? But maybe it isn't neccessary?

Comment: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
Does passing `dtype` parameter as 'str' or 'object' give you desired result?

Comment: yes, looks like that works -- using dtype as 'str' Thanks!